# How to Run a Random Function in Python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have two functions:

`functionA()` and `functionB()`

I do not care which function runs, but I do want just ONE of them to run randomly--ie, if I run the script a hundred times, both should be played near 50 times.

How can I program that into Python 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python, functions are first class citizens so you can put them in a list and then randomly select one of them at every turn using [`random.choice`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html#random.choice):

```
>>> import random

>>> functions = [functionA, functionB]
>>> for _ in range(100):
...     function = random.choice(functions)
...     function()
```

Comment: @RonE These are not function pointers. `functionA` is a reference to a function object. And the difference matters if you want an actual explanation.

Comment: How about instead of exactly specifying it to run 100 times in a for-loop, to program it to just randomly run one or the other function every time it is called upon?